# DateRangePicker from react-date-range not showing more than 2 months in infinite scrollable mode

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-date-range

I am using DateRangePicker from [react-date-range](https://hypeserver.github.io/react-date-range/) and I want a scrollable date range picker. I copied the exact code of [infinite scrollable daterangepicker](https://hypeserver.github.io/react-date-range/#daterangepicker) from their demo into my react project but it showed wrong results. I also searched a lot about this but did not find any related article. I am attaching the screenshots of code and results as well.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCDer.png)

[First month being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0bdo.png)

[Second month being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0rB3.png)

[No months being shown after that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb6zJ.png)

I tried searching about this issue on github and stackOverflow too but could not find any solution. It is difficult to find any solution because this package is also not updated since 2 years and is unmaintained. If anyone can help solve it, would be awesome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working Fine.
Note That I'm using  *"react-date-range": "^1.4.0"* version. Check yours version of *react-date-range* package. I have also faced problem in the latest version of *react-date-range* package.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-date-range';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';

import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css';
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css';

import './DateRange.css';
const DateRangeComp = () => {
    const [range, setRange] = useState([
        {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
            key: 'selection',
        },
    ]);

    // open close
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    // get the target element to toggle
    const refOne = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', hideOnEscape, true);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', hideOnEnter, true);
        document.addEventListener('click', hideOnClickOutside, true);
    }, []);

    const hideOnEscape = (e) => {
        // console.log(e.key)
        if (e.key === 'Escape') {
            setOpen(false);
        }
    };
    const hideOnEnter = (e) => {
        // console.log(e.key)
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            setOpen(false);
        }
    };
    const hideOnClickOutside = (e) => {
        if (refOne.current && !refOne.current.contains(e.target)) {
            setOpen(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='calendarWrap'>
            <Button variant='outlined' color='inherit' onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                {`${format(range[0].startDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')} - ${format(
                    range[0].endDate,
                    'MM/dd/yyyy',
                )}`}
            </Button>

            <div ref={refOne} style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 999 }}>
                {open && (
                    <DateRangePicker
                        onChange={(item) => setRange([item.selection])}
                        editableDateInputs={true}
                        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
                        ranges={range}
                        months={2}
                        direction='horizontal'
                        className='calendarElement'
                        showSelectionPreview={true}
                        responsive={true}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DateRangeComp;
```